# Cmake undefined referance error

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, catkin

I am having trouble getting Cmake to work. I am using ROS and catkin_make. I have read the following: 
[cmake undefined reference to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057107/cmake-undefined-reference-to-function)
[cmake undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327052/cmake-undefined-reference)

but still cannot seem to get it compile. I am attempting to use Google unit testing on my code. I am new to cmake and google testing. I am sure I am missing something very small and obvious.
I have my tests in one file "test_usbl.cpp" and a main that should call all my tests.

This is my file:

```
usbl
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── CMakeLists.txt~
    ├── include
    │   └── usbl
    │       └── usblSim.h
    ├── package.xml
    ├── src
    │   ├── usblSim.cpp
    │   └── usblSim.cpp~
    └── test
        ├── test_main.cpp
        └── test_usbl.cpp
```

and this is my CMakeList.txt:

```
    CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.3)
PROJECT(usbl)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

FIND_PACKAGE(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

FIND_PACKAGE(GTest REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
FIND_PACKAGE(Threads)

catkin_package( )

SET(INCLUDE_DIRS
  ${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  include/usbl
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${INCLUDE_DIRS})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/usbl)
SET(SRC
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/usblSim.cpp}
  )
SET(LIBS 
  ${ROS_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
  ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}


)

# simulator
#ADD_EXECUTABLE(usblSim src/usblSim.cpp)
add_library(usbl src/usblSim.cpp)
#TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(usblSim ${LIBS})



SET(USBL_TEST
  test/test_usbl.cpp
  test/test_main.cpp
  )

ADD_EXECUTABLE(test_usbl ${USBL_TEST})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_usbl ${LIBS})
```

This is giving me the error:

```
 CMakeFiles/test_usbl.dir/test/test_usbl.cpp.o: In function `meanTest_isEquel_Test::TestBody()':
/home/nathaniel/Documents/usbl/src/usbl/test/test_usbl.cpp:12: undefined reference to `usblSim::usblSim()'
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, had to make it:

```
SET(LIBS 
  ${ROS_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${GTEST_LIBRARIES}
  ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
  ${PROJECT_NAME}#This is the new line

)
```